# .ashx TransmitFile pdf not loading

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, httphandler

I am having issues with my ashx page sending a PDF document.

Here is what I have for my response code.
Update: Added whole ashx to answer some responses. 
`

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="deliverpdf" %>

Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.HttpContext
Imports Aspose.Words
Imports Aspose.Words.Reporting
Imports Aspose.Words.Saving




Public Class deliverpdf : Implements IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState

    Public Sub ProcessPDF(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"




        context.Session("errormessage") = ""

        Try
            Dim dataDir As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ApplicationRoot") & "app_data/Contracts/Customers/"
            Dim CustId As String = myCStr(context.Request.QueryString("cstid"))
            Dim sid As Integer = myCInt(context.Request.QueryString("sid"))
            Dim fileName As String = myCStr(context.Request.QueryString("name"))

            dataDir = dataDir & CustId & "/" & sid & "/" & fileName

            context.Response.Clear()
            context.Response.ClearContent()

            context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName)
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", dataDir.Length.ToString())
            context.Response.TransmitFile(dataDir)
            context.Response.End()


        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim dataDir As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ApplicationRoot") & "app_data/Contracts/Customers/"
            Dim CustId As String = myCStr(context.Request.QueryString("cstid"))
            Dim sid As Integer = myCInt(context.Request.QueryString("sid"))
            Dim fileName As String = myCStr(context.Request.QueryString("name"))

            context.Response.Clear()
            context.Session("errormessage") = ex.Message

        End Try

        context.Response.End()

    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class`
```

This page sends the file, however, once I download the file, all 3 major browsers say that it failed to load.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `dataDir`? Could you post the entire ashx file?

Comment: I edited the post to contain the whole ashx file. Thank you!